# Is yoghurt mixed with milk safe?

Tags: food-safety, milk, yogurt

I have always been told that you shouldn't drink milk and eat yoghurt together. So today in the kitchen channel when they made a smoothie with milk and yoghurt I was shocked. Since I couldn't find information online, I ask here: is it safe to drink milk and yoghurt together?

Comment: What on earth gave you the impression that mixing together any two safe food products would produce something 'unsafe'? Most especially two that are so similar.

Comment: @Tetsujin because yoghurt is made from milk by fermentation, it could spoil the milk or something. I have always been told that from my parents. I don't see why there could not be cases where two safe products produce something unsafe, or at least unpleasant. There are some places on internet that claim that for example milk with banana is unhealthy, but it's hard to find reliable sources.

Comment: I am thinking of the grade school lunchroom proctor reply to the kids who did not like the different foods on their plate touching.  "It all mixes in your stomach".

Comment: Note that we will not allow discussion of health claims  - there are so many philosophies (or beliefs or folklore) on which foods should or should not be mixed, eaten together or avoided altogether. Asking about food safety on a scientific basis is perfectly fine. For more information check the tag info for “food-safety”.

Comment: There are no two food items that become unsafe to consume on mixing. Even the worst edge cases I could think of are unsafe to handle, but not less safe to consume than the original - for example, don't pour vinegar into the lye used for brushing pretzels. There are a lot of cases where the mixing of two products in a given category of shelf-life can push the mixture into a category of much shorter shelf life - for example, if you mix sugar and water (both are shelf-stable individually), you get a syrup that needs refrigeration. But milk is already in the shortest category.

Comment: @rumtscho There’s one famous exception, though: The [common ink cap (*Coprinopsis atramentaria*)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprinopsis_atramentaria) is poisonous when combined with alcohol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that’s perfectly safe.

If your yogurt has live yogurt bacteria (so not pasteurized after fermentation), some of that bacteria would turn the fresh milk into yogurt if given enough time - but we are talking about hours in a rather warm environment, not in a smoothie that is mixed and then consumed rather quickly or stored in the fridge.

The milk is just to thin the smoothie without watering it down or the yogurt to add a bit of acidity without curdling the milk.

Comment: @AnswerMyQuestion Just commenting to say that, in case it isn't clear: Yoghurt bacteria will not ferment in your stomach despite it being warm. The conditions in the stomach are too acidic and the retention time is not long enough to result in any significant bacterial activity. However, live bacteria (assuming your yoghurt is live culture, not Pasteurized) do make it through the stomach to the lower intestine and are useful for good gut health.